# Undesirable scope bleed between components in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have a component `[ui-button]` ([github](https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-button/tree/feature/buttons)) where I'm adding a wrapping component called `ui-buttons` ([demo here](http://v11.development.ui-button.divshot.io/buttons-demo)). The problem is that the wrapping component seems to receive registrations *not only* from its children but from **ALL** children that are on the page! Effectively this property is acting like a static variable across all instances of `ui-buttons`. I didn't even know you could do this and in this case its definitely an undesirable effect.

In the demo link above try clicking on the the "disable the group" button and notice that it disables ALL buttons. So what am I doing?

Structurally it looks like this:

```
{{#ui-buttons as |group|}}
  {{ui-radio-button title='foo' group=group}}
  {{ui-radio-button title='bar' group=group}}
  {{ui-radio-button title='baz' group=group}}
{{/ui-buttons}}
```

In this process I have child elements (e.g., `ui-radio-button`) register themselves with `ui-buttons`. The item-level [registration code](https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-button/blob/feature/buttons/addon/mixins/item-messaging.js#L6-L11) is:

```
_registration: on('init', function() {
  const group = this.get('group');
  if(group) {
    group._registerItem(this);
  }
}),
```

and the [group-level registration code](https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-button/blob/feature/buttons/addon/components/ui-buttons.js#L25-L28) is:

```
_registerItem: function(child) {
  console.log('registering %o with %o', child, this.get('elementId'), this.get('_registeredItems.length'));
  this.get('_registeredItems').pushObject(child);
},
```

If you note the group-level registration has a "console.log" statement and that produces very encouraging results (it recognizes the element ID of the group as being distinct) alongside worrisome results (the registry "length" continues to grow across all):

[image: log]

I suspect this is down to *async* or *this* complexities but I'm now at a loss on how to proceed.

Comment: The demo link doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line of code

```
_registeredItems: new A([]),
```

That creates a single array one time (I believe when the component is parsed - on application load) and all your components are using it..

Best bet is to change it to

```
_registeredItems: Ember.computed(function() { 
  return new A([]); 
})
```

When `_registeredItems` is first accessed it creates the new array.